# Getting input hidden value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a javascript snippet in which I'd like to retrieve the value of a hidden input located in the first column of selected row :

```
var global_id = $(this).find("td:first").html();
console.log("value=" + global_id);
```

I get as result :

`value =<input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="2">`

When I try

```
 var global_id = $(this).find("td:first").val();
console.log("value=" + global_id);
```

I get as result :

`value =`

So, I need to know :

1. Why in the second way, the variable is empty
2. How can I resolve my code to retrieve the first input hidden value?

Comment: EDITED: Just noticed your middle result update. Tiny Giant has the answer anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reference the actual input element, not the containing element. This will find the input element if it is hidden using `type="hidden"`, using css or using jQuery's `hide()`

```
var global_id = $("td:first input:hidden:first", this).val();
console.log("value=" + global_id);
```